# Squid ACL - IP ranges not working

Tags: squid

In my Squid FW I have a list of domains where I want to bypass NTLM. I have achieved that with the following:

```
#URLS to bypass the trip
acl BYPASS_DOMAIN dstdomain "C:/bypass_domain.txt"
#TAG: Bypass NTLM & Trip
 http_access allow BYPASS_DOMAIN
 always_direct allow BYPASS_DOMAIN
```

Now I need to bypass a range of IPs, for example 192.168.0.0/24.
I have tried adding this as a line in *bypass_domain.txt* but it doesn't work.
If I add the exact IP (ie 192.1683.0.111) to *bypass_domain.txt* it does work.

I have also tried the following, but that failed too:

```
#URLS to bypass the trip
acl BYPASS_IP src 192.168.0.0/24
#TAG: Bypass NTLM & Trip
 http_access allow BYPASS_IP
 always_direct allow BYPASS_IP
```

I have multiple ranges that I need to bypass, so it will be a pain to list every IP.
Any ideas where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please RTFM http://wiki.squid-cache.org/SquidFaq/SquidAcl#ACL_elements.

The ACL type "dstdomain" compares things against URL hostname. An IP address *range* is not a vaid URL hostname. Which was why your first attempt did not work.

The ACL type "src" matches your client IP addresses where *requests* are coming from. Which is why that second attempt does not work.

PS. always_direct is useless unless you have cache_peer or never_direct rules configured. You probably do not need that part at all.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers. This helped me resolve the problem. I did have never_direct configured, so kept the always_direct rule in